# Problemas com requisição GET Angular 7

Tags: angular, restful, get, angular-7

Boa noite pessoal, estou tentando criar uma requisição do tipo `get` na minha aplicação Angular, mas está estourando esse erro. Não consegui entender o que quer dizer e nenhuma das possíveis soluções que testei não funcionaram. Alguém saberia me dizer o que esse erro significa?

**Stack do erro**

```
/home/laura/Documentos/Jobs/Seleções/Even3-Desafio/Desafio-Front-End/node_modules/webpack/schemas/plugins/optimize/OccurrenceOrderChunkIdsPlugin.json: Unexpected end of JSON input
    SyntaxError: /home/laura/Documentos/Jobs/Seleções/Even3-Desafio/Desafio-Front-End/node_modules/webpack/schemas/plugins/optimize/OccurrenceOrderChunkIdsPlugin.json: Unexpected end of JSON input
        at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
        at Object.Module._extensions..json (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:27)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/laura/Documentos/Jobs/Seleções/Even3-Desafio/Desafio-Front-End/node_modules/webpack/lib/optimize/OccurrenceChunkOrderPlugin.js:8:16)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
```

**app.server.js**

```
axios({
    url: 'http://developer.marvel.com/v1/public/comics',
    method: 'get'
});
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    Subscription
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { preserveWhitespacesDefault } from '@angular/compiler';
import { Comic } from './comic';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  preserveWhitespaces: true
})


export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  ngOnInit(): void {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Laura, ativa o F12 no browser e inspeciona a aba network para ver o que a chamada da url está devolvendo. Eu testei a url direto no browser e recebi um 404. Por outro lado, não vejo a chamada ao método no seu código. Outra observação: comente o "throw new Error" do seu AppComponent.ngOnInit.

Comment: Por favor, adicione a sua pergunta o codigo onde você faz a requisição.

Comment: Victor Henrique eu acreditava que o código da requisição era a parte do código que usa a biblioteca axios. Se não for esse o caso, então acredito que eu não tenha esse código.